# How to check for specific ACF sub fields value?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have some ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) repeater table with different sub fields. Now i would like to check for specific text values inserted to one of these and print a different div class based on what value is stored here.

I have tried the following but this does not work.

```
<?php
if (get_sub_field('rls_status') == "ONLINE") {
  echo '<div class="online">Status: ONLINE'</div>;
}
elseif (get_sub_field('rls_status') == "OFFLINE") {
  echo '<div class="offline">Status: OFFLINE';</div>
}?>
```

Comment: I think you  marked up my answer. Could you please mark it as the accepted answer if this solved your issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**1) Correct the formatting on your echoed strings**

Your closing quote marks and semi-colons are out of place in your echoed strings.

Here is the corrected markup:

```
<?php
    if (get_sub_field('rls_status') == "ONLINE") {
        echo '<div class="online">Status: ONLINE</div>';
    } elseif (get_sub_field('rls_status') == "OFFLINE") {
        echo '<div class="offline">Status: OFFLINE</div>';
    }
?>
```

**2) Check the data is accessible**

Look at the data stored in the ACF option.
To render in the DOM use:

`<?php var_dump(get_sub_field('rls_status')); ?>`

To look in your PHP error logs (my preference as it's often easier to view):

```
<?php
    error_log("--------- START of my log -------------");
    error_log(var_export(get_sub_field('rls_status'), true));
    error_log(gettype(get_sub_field('rls_status'))); // Check the type is string
    error_log("--------- END of my log -------------");
?>
```

(Don't forget the `true` as a second parameter in the `var_export` function)

If you can't see the data or it's not what you expected there's a few things to check.

1. Have you definitely saved the data in the CMS? Double check it's there. Made this mistake often. I forget to save the page.
2. Check that you can see that data in the Database in the options table.
3. You're in a repeater so you're correct to use `get_sub_field()` but just double check `get_field()` incase you've got confused somewhere.
4. Check the repeater is working by either error_logging or rendering a h1 outside of an if to see if you go round the loop the same amount of times as what you have repeater items for in the CMS. Alternatively look at the section "Inspect all the ACF data for that post" in my answer below.

**3) Check it isn't already working but appearing not to**

Double check the DOM by inspecting and seeing if the code block is rendered but just not visible.

To be absolutely sure I would do the following:

```
<?php
if (get_sub_field('rls_status') == "ONLINE") {
  error_log("--------- WE ARE ONLINE- WHAAAAAT?! -------------");
  echo '<div class="online">Status: ONLINE'</div>;
} elseif (get_sub_field('rls_status') == "OFFLINE") {
  error_log("--------- WE ARE OFFLINE BOOOOOOO! -------------");
  echo '<div class="offline">Status: OFFLINE';</div>
} else {
  error_log("--------- NEITHER?! -------------");
  error_log(var_export(get_sub_field('rls_status'), true));
}
?>
```

**4) Inspect all the ACF data for that post**

You can see all the data for a post using the `get_fields()` function.

```
<?php
    error_log("--------- START of my log -------------");        
    error_log(var_export(get_fields(), true));
    error_log("--------- END of my log -------------");
?>
```

See if you can see what you're looking for or what you're missing.